# GPU/CUDA: Re-ordering device memory

Tags: c++, arrays, cuda, gpu

I have a multi dimension array stored in device memory. I want to ["permute"](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html)/["transpose"](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html), that is, re-arrange its elements according to new order of dimensions.

For example, if I have a 2D array

```
A = [0, 1, 2
     3, 4, 5]
```

I want to change the order of dimension so I get

```
B = [0, 3
     1, 4
     2, 5]
```

This re-ordering practically copies the elements that are stored in memory in the order `[0,1,2,3,4,5]` and return a new ordering `[0,3,1,4,2,5]`.

I know how to map the indices from `A` to `B`, my question is how I can execute this mapping efficiently on device using cuda?

Comment: You could just leave the memory as is and use the alternative indexing scheme. That is what every sane linear algebra library does.

Comment: @talonmies I wish I could... but its part of a bigger library and the fansy indexing is not supported

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check this http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/efficient-matrix-transpose-cuda-cc/

**Naive Matrix Transpose:**

```
__global__ void transposeNaive(float *odata, const float *idata)
{
  int x = blockIdx.x * TILE_DIM + threadIdx.x;
  int y = blockIdx.y * TILE_DIM + threadIdx.y;
  int width = gridDim.x * TILE_DIM;

  for (int j = 0; j < TILE_DIM; j+= BLOCK_ROWS)
    odata[x*width + (y+j)] = idata[(y+j)*width + x];
}
```

**Coalesced Transpose Via Shared Memory:**
[image]

```
__global__ void transposeCoalesced(float *odata, const float *idata)
{
  __shared__ float tile[TILE_DIM][TILE_DIM];

  int x = blockIdx.x * TILE_DIM + threadIdx.x;
  int y = blockIdx.y * TILE_DIM + threadIdx.y;
  int width = gridDim.x * TILE_DIM;

  for (int j = 0; j < TILE_DIM; j += BLOCK_ROWS)
     tile[threadIdx.y+j][threadIdx.x] = idata[(y+j)*width + x];

  __syncthreads();

  x = blockIdx.y * TILE_DIM + threadIdx.x;  // transpose block offset
  y = blockIdx.x * TILE_DIM + threadIdx.y;

  for (int j = 0; j < TILE_DIM; j += BLOCK_ROWS)
     odata[(y+j)*width + x] = tile[threadIdx.x][threadIdx.y + j];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm a GPU newbie so it might take me a while to parse. But in the attached diagram, shouldn't the green column be vertical in `odata`?

Comment: The objective pictured in the diagram is to have coalesced access for both the *reads* from `idata` and the *writes* to `odata`.  In a nutshell, coalescing in this context will be achieved by "horizontal" access.  Therefore the orientation of the yellow operation (read from `idata`) and the green operation (write to `odata`) are intended to both have "horizontal" access as they touch the global data arrays.  The actual in-tile transposing is occurring in shared memory, which is depicted by the tile block in the center of the diagram.  This is where the reads and writes are horizontal/vertical.